# Struts 2 - comparing objects

Tags: struts2

i'm trying to compare a value to an Enum in Struts:

```
<s:if test="%{myValue == com.app.core.Values.ALL}" />
```

where `myValue` is declared in the Action and `com.app.core.Values` is declared in another project that is referenced to this one.

Any tips?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Accessing static properties](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8.1/docs/ognl-basics.html#OGNLBasics-Accessingstaticproperties) in the Struts documentation.

I think what you need is:

```
<s:if test="myValue == @com.app.core.Values@ALL">
```

You may also need to set the struts configuration constant struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess to true.

Comment: +1 Sometimes it's more clean to define a method in your action that does the comparison